# PetaPoco query complaining about incorrect order by syntax

Tags: petapoco

Given this seemingly easy query:

```
var sql = Sql.Builder
             .Append("SELECT * FROM Log")
             .Append("WHERE ApplicationId=@0", 1)
             .Append("ORDER BY @0 @1", "Timestamp", "ASC");
return _db.Page<Log>(1, 25, sql);
```

Incorrect syntax near '@2'. (@2 ends up evaluating to @1 in the last append)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `.Append("ORDER BY @0 @1", "Timestamp", "ASC");` because `Timestamp` and `ASC` are being interpreted as params.

You will need to concatenate the string there:

```
 .Append(String.Format("ORDER BY {0} {1}", "Timestamp", "ASC"));
```

**BEWARE** that this it's a possible sql injection attack vector. **Sanitize your inputs**.

Comment: While your solution works I'd like comment that the SQL Builder API is misleading. Multiple arguments work in append on other parts of the sql but not the order by? Really..?

Comment: The problem it's not about multiple. PetaPoco generates sql params and then pass them to ADO.net. In ORDER BY the arguments are not params.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize it passed the parameters directly to ado.net. Thanks.